# What IP Address range does Auth0 use to connect to custom database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ip-address, auth0

I'm setting up [Auth0](http://auth0.com) integration with an application that uses an existing database that stored usernames and password hashes. The database is stored in Azure SQL Database, and I need to configure the firewall rules to allow Auth0 to be able to connect to the database.

What is the IP address range that Auth0 uses to connect to custom databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Auth0 configuration page for setting up the Database Action Scripts for connecting to and working with your custom database, there is a list of originating IP Addresses below the script editor. You can setup the Azure SQL Database Server IP Whitelist to allows the specific IP Addresses listed.

The display of the IP Addresses, look like the following, but you'll want to use the IP Addresses it lists on your account just in case they may differ from this screenshot.

[image]